# Adding Static Library for Unreal engine 5.1 with Cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, static-libraries, unreal-engine5, rdkit

I want to use the Chemistry engine *Rdkit* as a static C++ library for Unreal engine 5.1.
However, I cannot get Configuring complete in CMake.

operation system: Windows 11

visual studio 2019

I did not make changes to the CMakeList.txt Rdkit provided.

The CMake Command I used

```bash
cmake -DRDK_BUILD_PYTHON_WRAPPERS=OFF -DB00ST_ROOT=C:/boost -DEIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR=C:/eigen3 -DRDK_BUILD_INCHI_SUPPORT=ON -DRDK_BUILD_AVALON_SUPPORT=ON -DRDK_BUILD_PGSQ
-=ON -DARK_BUILD_STATIC_LIBS=ON -DARK_BUILD_CPP_ONLY=ON -DARK_INSTALL_INTREE=OFF -DPostgreSQL_ROOT="C:\ProgramFiles\PostgreSQL\9.5" -G"VisualStudio 16 2019" ..
```

Log detail

```bash
Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.22000.0 to target Windows 10.0. 22621.
The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.29. 30148.0
The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.29. 30148.0
Detecting C compiler ABI info
Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Host×64/×64/cl.exe - skipped
Detecting C compile features Detecting C compile features - done
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (×86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Host×64/×64/cl.exe - skipped
Detecting CXX compile features
- - Detecting CXX compile features - done
Disabling boost::stacktrace on non-linux platform
Found Catch2 source in C:/RDKit/External/catch/catch
CATCH: C:/RDKit/External/catch/catch/single_include/catch?
- - Could NOT find InchI in system locations (missing: INCHI_LIBRARY INCHI_INCLUDE_DIR)
CUSTOM_INCHI_PATH = C:/RDKit/External/INCHI-API
Found InchI software locally
Found Boost: C:/boost (found suitable version "1.66.0", minimum required is "1.58.0")
Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed
Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
Looking for pthread_create in pthread - not found
Found Threads: TRUE
- - Could NOT find Boost (missing: system serialization iostreams) (found suitable version "1.66.0", minimum required is "1.58.0")
CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:452 (find_package):
Policy CMP0074 is not set: find_package uses <PackageNames_ROOT variables. Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0074' for policy details. Use the cmake_policy
command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
CMake variable PostgreSQL_ROOT is set to:
C: Program Files\ PostgreSQL\9.5
For compatibility, CMake is ignoring the variable.
This warning is for project developers. Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.26/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
Could NOT find PostgreSQL (missing: PostgreSQL_LIBRARY
PostgreSQL_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.26/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:600(-FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.26/Modules/FindPostgreSQL.cmake:272(find_package_handle_standard_args)
(MakeLists.txt:452 (find_package) Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Welcome any idea or approach about adding a system can simulate realistic chem in UE5.

If any information is needed please let me know, Thank you <3

Comment: Looks like you are missing a few dependencies: `Could NOT find Boost ...`, `Could NOT find PostgreSQL ...` - Fix that first.

Comment: `-DB00ST_ROOT=C:/boost` looks wrong. Shouldn't that be `-DBOOST_ROOT=C:/boost` ?

Comment: Setting value of variable `PostgreSQL_ROOT` as `"C:\ProgramFiles\PostgreSQL\9.5"` is wrong too. Because of backslashes, this value is treated as `C: Program Files\ PostgreSQL\9.5` (you may find the latter in the configure log).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem by following these steps:

1. reinstalled Boost.
2. added the missing dependencies.
3. made some changes to the CMakeLists.txt file, specifically

```
set(FREETYPE_ROOT_DIR "C:/freetype")
set(FREETYPE_INCLUDE_DIRS "${FREETYPE_ROOT_DIR}/include")
set(FREETYPE_LIBRARY "${FREETYPE_ROOT_DIR}/lib/freetype.lib")

set(ZLIB_ROOT "C:/zlib")
set(ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS "${ZLIB_ROOT}/include")
set(ZLIB_LIBRARIES "${ZLIB_ROOT}/lib/zlib.lib")
```

4. I added additional flags to the CMake command

```
cmake .. -DRDK_BUILD_INCHI_SUPPORT=OFF -DRDK_BUILD_AVALON_SUPPORT=OFF -DRDK_BUILD_PYTHON_WRAPPERS=OFF -DRDK_BUILD_CPP_TESTS=OFF -DRDK_BUILD_THREADSAFE_SSS=OFF -DRDK_BUILD_SWIG_WRAPPERS=OFF -DRDK_INSTALL_STATIC_LIBS=ON -DBOOST_ROOT=C:/boost
```